# Do I have contamination?

Tags: contamination, krausen, starsan

Beer Kit: Brewferm Tarwebier

This was my first time using StarSan as it's hard to get in my neck of woods. Is this some ugly Krausen or contamination, if so what type?

Is there any recovery from this, can I rack from underneath it, spray it with some StarSan?

I stored the StarSan for a few days after cleaning bottles, before I reused it to clean my FV, I that that was okay to do? could this be the source of the contamination, some bottles had a few little specks of mold? :(
[image]

Comment: Looks OK to me. How's it smell and taste?

Comment: I'm just a bit paranoid if I'm using the StarSan correctly.
It smells fine, I'll go give it a taste.

Comment: Taste no evil. I think I'm good boys and girls!

Comment: Can anyone else see the horse?

Comment: Yup. Definitely a stallion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smell: Smells like beer.
Look: Looks like beer.
Taste: Tastes like beer.
Verdict: It's beer!

I think the issue here was paranoia of using a new sanitiser and tech. The Krausen looked to me like colony of 'something' floating on clear head, instead of all the foam looking brown and Krausen like.

Answer (score 1):

For any beer you suspect to be contaminated, the bottom line is that if it tastes good and smells good, it is good. Also, the brown gunk in your fermenter looks like protein that would have clumped together during the boil. It's common to see it floating around on the krausen (yeast foam) during fermentation. Hope the beer turns out well!

Comment: Thanks for the post. Every other time my krausen looks fine and like brown foam this time it just looked very different and it weirded me out.